# CardView shadow not shown

Tags: android, cardview, android-elevation

After trying almost everything in stackoverflow and deeply digging into my code, I realized that the problem with `CardView's` shadow was `setRotationY()`.

The `CardView` was inside a `RecyclerView` and for some reasons (rtl) I had to `rotateY` both `recyclerView` and its children to 180.

After removing the rotations the shadow was finally revealed. What's with it? how can I have the shadow when rotating? Is there any trigger that can redraw the shadow or anything?

Comment: Have you tried adding "  android:hardwareAccelerated="true" ?

Comment: Can you share screenshots of the behavior that you describe?

Comment: @TheHound.developer hardwareAccelerated is true by default. If u mean making it false, when its false cardView effects are totally disabled; including radius